# XML Dom parsing in IE

Tags: javascript, xml, internet-explorer-8

Parsing of XML using DOM doesn't work in certain IE browsers . But the same code works in others browsers like firefox or chrome.

Note : The same parsing logic works in my IE browser , whereas it doesn't work in my client IE browser!!

Is there any plugin(or settings) I should include to make it work in IE

Comment: What version of IE are you using? How big is the xml document?

Comment: I use IE8(my client also). I use XML to store the data received from Db query. Hence the size of xml depends on the query results.But this XML parsing doesn't work even for a very small xml document.

Comment: Please don't ask questions saying "it doesn't work" without saying exactly what you did and exactly how it failed. Would you email your doctor to say "I don't feel well" and expect a diagnosis?

Answer (score 0):

This jQuery plugin has always done me good when I've had to parse a XML response from a web server. It's also quite easy to use:

http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/XmlDOM

Consider the an XML tree like:

```
<products>
    <product>
        <!-- etc... -->
```

Using the aforementioned plugin, you can iterate through all the products like(x is a variable containing the xml string):

```
$.xmlDOM(x).find("product").each(function (i, e) {
    // access the "product" via the "e" variable...
});
```

Comment: Am using AJAX not JQuery.So what might be the problem so that its not working in my clients browser